# Crawl Database Size

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, database, sql, crawl

So I have a SharePoint 2010 farm. Last month I noticed it was getting unreasonably bigger, everything was working fine though.
Then I noticed that *Search_Service_Application_CrawlerStore.....* database reached 200Gb.
I tried shrinking it (simple recovery) but it doesn't seem to care.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please tell us which part of the databases consumes most of the disk-space. Is it the data file (.mdf) or the logfile (.ldf). The correct solution heavily depends on that.

Comment: It's the Data File.

Comment: Then try the solution already provided by Alok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try these steps below. These will empty your search index before repopulating it and one will also loose crawl history.

1. Central Admin-> Search service admin -> Index Reset. This will erase all the content Index.
2. DB Server->Choose the Crawl DB ->Shrink the Crawl DB files.
3. Start a full crawl.

Reference [Link explaining the steps](http://achildstechnologyblog.blogspot.com/2014/08/sharepoint-crawl-db-size-was-too-large.html)

Comment: I think the best time to try that is when no one is using it, so I'll get back at you when I run it.